# Stop start function on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function that rotate div inside another div. How can i start and stop rotating the div on button click. One button to start rotating another to stop it. And is there a way to rotate div only when i slide slider right or left not like it is now on mouse move? Please help. Function for rotating div :

```js
var img = $(".inner");

if (img.length > 0) {
  var offset = img.offset();

  function mouse(evt) {
    var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
    var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
    var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
    var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
    var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
    var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
    img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
    img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  }
  $(".inner").mousemove(mouse);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black; display:block; ">
```

Comment: `One button to start rotating another to stop it` I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that the `inner` will rotate by click on "right" or "left" buttons?

Comment: You could toggle a class on your div and wrap your rotation code in an if that checks for the presence of the class.

Comment: The rotation is using mouse event values (pageX, pageY), what do you want the click event to do? What is the rotation going to be based on if you use a click event to do it? Please can you explain more clearly what the desired behaviour is as the function you provided doesn't seem at all suitable to what you are requesting.

Comment: I've made a simple example for you here jsfiddle.net/KAngel7/da3e5fLe/, hope it's help!

Comment: it should act like is acting right now (rotation)but i need start rotation on button click and stop  it means when i pick an image inside div and the div is without rotation on button click start i can manipulate div rotation and on button stop the div stay in condition that is at the end of manipulation and cant be rotated any more and again start button start manipulation of div stop stop manipulation in state that it is in. i hope i am not confusing you more that it was on the begining :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `class` to detect if `img` has clicked or not:

**Self Click Version:**

```js
var img = $(".inner");
var offset = img.offset();

function mouse(evt) {
  var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
  var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
  img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}

img.on('click', function(e) {

  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');

});

img.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  if (!img.hasClass('clicked')) {
    mouse(evt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black; display:block; ">
```

**Button Click Version:**

```js
var img = $(".inner");
var offset = img.offset();

function mouse(evt) {
  var center_x = (offset.left) + (img.width() / 2);
  var center_y = (offset.top) + (img.height() / 2);
  var mouse_x = evt.pageX;
  var mouse_y = evt.pageY;
  var radians = Math.atan2(mouse_x - center_x, mouse_y - center_y);
  var degree = (radians * (180 / Math.PI) * -1) + 90;
  img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
  img.css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)');
}

$('#Stop').on('click', function(e) {
  img.addClass('clicked');
});

$('#Start').on('click', function(e) {
  img.removeClass('clicked');
});

img.on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  if (!img.hasClass('clicked')) {
    mouse(evt);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner clicked" style="width:100px; height:100px; background-color:black; display:block; ">
</div>
<button id="Start">Start</button>
<button id="Stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: This is what i want:) Thx very much. And one more time thx. Im nevbie in jquery.

Comment: Glad to help you. just add `clicked` class in your `html` `<div class="inner clicked">` See updated.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can use:

```
$('selector').on('click', function(){

}
```

To rotate you can use Jquery animate:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/